# How to say ‘go back’ in German

Tags: english-to-german

I am trying to write the sentence ‘We go back to school on Wednesday’ but I don’t know how to say it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We do not provide a translation service here. Please state your own research, what did you come up with? Where are you having trouble? Then we will help gladly.

Comment: "Wir gehen am Mittwoch zurück zur Schule" could be a dictionary-like translation. I don't know which way one could go to find an *acceptable* translation for one precise sentence or for one special predicate like "_go back to school_" that is not listed in any dictionary when you have the intuition that a word-by-word-translation doesn't sound natural.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one possibility:

> Ab Mittwoch müssen wir wieder in die Schule.
>
> Mittwoch fängt die Schule wieder an.
>
> Ab Mittwoch haben wir wieder Schule.